# How does gearing work in an unlisted property fund?

Tags: investing, fund-manager

I am trying to work out how gearing is calculated on a Fund I am looking at. It has an example that says if the Fund is worth $10m and gearing is 35% then the 'gross' value of the fund is $15.38m. However when I calculate it I get a gross value of $13.5m (I did 35% of $10m and added this to the $10m value of the Fund)

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Many thanks

Comment: 0.65*15.38 equals 9.997

Comment: If OP is a personal investor, then this **is** on-topic for PF.

Answer (score 2):

Rearranging the @mhoran_psprep comment: `$10M / (1 - 35%) = $15.38M`.